# Delete USB history (regedit) with script

Tags: javascript, powershell, usb, registry

I have a javascript and Powershell script allowing to detect a usb plug, and which shows me a pop up. Indeed, my script only detects new usb keys that have not yet been plugged into the system. That's why I would like to delete the usb key history from my computer, like USB OBLIVION does, in order to have as a new connection to each usb plug.

I don't see what I need to add to my script... I have already tried deleting the content of:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try these, but don't forget to wipe the from them other 3 paths as well

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\WPDBUSENUM
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\Devices\

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using WMI Event subscriptions, this works whatever the usb key is already known or not, but do not clear the registry :

to detect usb plug :

```
Register-CIMIndicationEvent –Query `
   "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance IsA 'Win32_LogicalDisk'" `
   –SourceIdentifier "WMIInsert" –Action { Write-Host `
   "$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name) plugged!`n" }
```

to detect usb ejection :

```
Register-CIMIndicationEvent –Query `
   "Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance IsA 'Win32_LogicalDisk'" `
   –SourceIdentifier "WMIEject" –Action { Write-Host `
   "$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name) ejected!`n" }
```

`Within 1` means to detect every one second. Depending on your needs, you can configure `Within 30` for example to look it for every 30 seconds (every plug or ejection in the meantime are captured as well).

the `-Action` parameter let you do whatever you want since this is a scriptblock (In the example I provided the event is only displayed to the console).

And do not forget that StackOverflow is not a free coding service, so next time, please share the piece of code where you have got a problem or a bug.